# Sizing relay for inrush current

Tags: relay

When sizing relays do you take into account the inrush current?  For example, if I have a load that draws 2.0A inrush and 0.75A afterward, do I select a relay that have to handle the higher inrush load?

Answer (score 1):

Some relays are rated for certain types of inrush (eg. "Tungsten" loads or some are rated for compressor or other motor loads) and may therefore use particular contact alloys or other design features to avoid problems.

Generally you should never exceed the ratings unless it's explicitly allowed in the datasheet- to ignore that could lead to reduced life and/or contacts welded shut.